# Average runtime random search without replacement

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Consider an algorithm that is tasked with searching the array A. Let *n* be the size of the array, let *i* be a random number between 1 and *n*. Finally, *k* is the target object we are searching for. If A[*i*] = k, we have a match. If A[*i*] != k, we pick a new random *i*. The algorithm terminates when we have established a match or we have checked all the elements in the array (k does not exist in A).

I am trying to figure out the Average Runtime of this, but am at a loss.

Comment: Hint: figure out the probabilities and then calculate the expectation.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If the key is present, the probability to find it at the first attempt is $p_1=\dfrac1n$. Then the probability to find it at the second attempt is $p_2=\dfrac{1-p_1}{n-1}$ (because the first attempt must have failed and there are $n-1$ equiprobable choices left). The probability to find it at the third attempt is $p_3=\dfrac{1-p_1-p_2}{n-2}$. And so on.

After having computed all probabilities, obtain the expectation. *Note that there is a nice simplification.*

If the key is not present, the expectation is $n$. Finally, combine the two expectations.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to @Yves Daoust, But I want to calculate the expected runtime easily.

**If key is present:**

Let $T$ be the runtime, what we want to calculate is $E[T]$.

**when $1\leq T \leq n $:**

$Pr(T\geq i)=\dfrac{n-1}{n}\dfrac{n-2}{n-1}...\dfrac{n-i+1}{n-i}=\dfrac{n-i+1}{n}$.

**when $ T \geq n $:**

$Pr(T> i)=0$

Because $T$ is **non-negative integer:**

$E[T]=\sum_{i \in N^+}Pr(T \geq i)=\dfrac{\sum_{i}i}{n}=\dfrac{n-1}{2}$

**If key is not present:**

The algorithm has to select $n$ times.